# Bending arm causes odd deformation

Tags: armature

I am attempting to make a simple rig. Whenever I try to bend any body parts, particularly the arms and legs, however, they leave an odd gap where they are bent
[image]

I need the arm to bend in a smooth way like in the picture below, does anyone know how?[image]

I have attempted to change the weight painting, and I have tried searching through forums, but I have been unable to find any solution to this problem yet.

Blend file [image]

Comment: You can upload your .blend file here blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to be able to help you

Comment: How would I upload the .blend file? Would I use dropbox or another similar cloud site, or is there a simpler way?

Comment: You can upload your .blend file on: blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com then provide the link in your question

Comment: [Link to file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3386/) (I cant add multiple links to the main post because my reputation is too low rip so i added it here)

Comment: That's a frequently asked question. The cause of the problem is definitely incorrect weights. You need to paint weights. I would recommend watching some video tutorials on YouTube or somewhere else on weight painting a character since the answer will be easiest to understand while watching how it's done. A text answer with pictures that you may get here might be harder to follow and understand.

Answer (score -1):

might be caused because you have a low poly figure with (high?) subdivision.
The subdevision performs a smooth over the low poly figure.
creating artifacts.

- copy your blend file, apply subdiv, then do another autoweights with bones.

Its always is a bit tricky but it might look better.
Sometimes people add extra bonus just to keep things stable, (ea rigify feed solution)..
placing of the bones is essential

Comment: i have applied the subdivision modifier, and I have then automatically applied weight painting. The issue is a lot less apparent, but it is still there, and the lower arm bone has no weight paint associated with it.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is only one quality solution to that:

Adding intermediate bone in between the two bones. 
With rotation interBone.rotation = slerp(bone1.rotation, bone2.rotation, 0.5)